# Algorithm to tell when we've processed a complex variable path expression while parsing?

Tags: algorithm, parsing

I am working on a compiler for a homemade programming language and I am stuck on how to convert the lexical token stream into a tree of commands for constructing a DOM-like tree. The "tree of commands" will still be a list, essentially emmitting events in a way that describes how to create a tree, from partial information provided by the lexer. (This language is like CoffeeScript in a way, indentation based, or like XML with indentation focus).

I am stuck on how to tell when a variable path has been discovered. A variable path can be simple, or complex, as these examples demonstrate:

```
foo
foo.bar
foo.bar[baz].hello[and][goodday].there
this[is[even[more.complicated].wouldnt.you[say]]]
```

They could get more complicated still, if we handled dynamic interpolation of strings, such as:

```
foo[`bar${x}abc`].baz
```

But in my simple lang, there are two relevant things, "paths", and "terms". Terms are anything `/a-z/` for now, and paths are chaining together and nesting, like the first examples.

For demonstration purposes, everything else is a simple "term" of 1 word, so you might have this:

```
abc foo.bar[baz].hello[and][goodday].there, one foo.bar
```

It forms a simple tree.

Right now I have a lexer which spits out the tokens, so basically:

```
abc
[SPACE]
foo
.
bar
[
baz
]
.
hello
[
and
]
[
goodday
]
.
there
,
[SPACE]
one
[SPACE]
foo
.
bar
```

That is at least how I broke it up initially.

So given that sequence of strings, how can you generate messages to tell the *parser* how to build a tree?

```
term
nest-down
term
period
term
open-square
and
close-square
...
```

That is the stream of tokens with a name now, but it is not a tree yet. I would like this:

```
term-start
  term # value: abc
term-end
nest-down
term-path-start
  term-start
    term # value: foo
  term-end
  period
  term-start
    term # value: bar
  term-end
  term-nest-start
    term-start
      term # value: and
    term-and
  term-nest-end
...
```

I have been struggling with this example for several days now (boiled down from a complex real-world scenario). I cant seem to figure out how to keep track of all the information you need to make a decision on when to say "this structure is done now, close it out" sort of thing. Wondering if you know how to get past this.

Note, I don't need the last tree to actually be a tree structure visually, I just need it to generate those messages which can be interpreted on the other end and used to construct a tree at runtime.

Comment: For most languages, a simple greedy algorithm works. The term continues until it can't continue any more, so it's done when the next input token is not a term-building operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to construct a tree from a list without having the description of the tree in some form. Often, in relation to parsing, the description of this tree is given by a context-free grammar (CFG).

Then you create a parser on the basis of this given CFG. The lexical token stream is given as an input to the parser. The parser organizes the lexical tokens into a tree by using some parsing algorithm.

The parser emits commands for syntax tree construction based on the rules it uses during parsing. On entering into a rule a command "rule X enter" is emitted, on exiting a rule a command "exit X rule" is emitted. When you accept a lexical token then a "token forward" is emitted with its lexeme characters. Some grammars, namely these in ABNF format, support repetitions of elements. Depending from these repetitions the syntax tree might be represented as lists or arrays.

Then a builder module receives this commands and builds a tree, or uses the commands for the specific task with the listener pattern.

I have co-authored (2021) a paper describing a list of commands for building a concrete/abstract syntax trees, depending on CFG's structure, that are used in the parsers generated by parser generator Tunnel Grammar Studio.

The paper is named "Тhe Expressive Power of the Statically Typed Concrete Syntax Trees". It is in an open-access journal (intentionally). The commands are in section "4.3 Syntax Structure Construction Commands". The article is bit "compressed", due to space limitations, and it is not really intended to be a software development guide, but to note the taken approach. It might give you some ideas.

Another co-authored paper of mine, from 2021 named "A Parsing Machine Architecture Encapsulating Different Parsing Approaches" (also in open-access journal) describes a general form of parsing machine and its modules. There Fig.1, p.33, will give you a quick description.

Disclaimer: I have made the parser generator.